# Why was camelot not found even if camelot is already on my computer?

Tags: python, import, pip, installation

Here is the code where I am trying to import camelot:

```
import camelot as cl
```

Here is the response:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-360275993d18> in <module>
----> 1 import camelot as cl
      2 tables = cl.read_pdf('C:\\2019.pdf', pages='47', flavor='stream')
      3 tables[0].plot('text')

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'camelot'
```

Here is what happens when I check the pip list. Camelot is already installed:

```
Package          Version
---------------- --------
camelot-py       0.8.0
chardet          3.0.4
click            7.1.2
Django           2.2.12
et-xmlfile       1.0.1
jdcal            1.4.1
numpy            1.18.5
opencv-python    4.2.0.34
openpyxl         3.0.3
pandas           1.0.4
pdfminer.six     20200517
pip              20.1.1
pycryptodome     3.9.7
PyPDF2           1.26.0
python-dateutil  2.8.1
pytz             2019.3
setuptools       41.2.0
six              1.15.0
sortedcontainers 2.2.2
sqlparse         0.3.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this but instead of 2.7, use the python version you have.

`python2.7 -m pip install camelot-py`

#### Edit:

My research tells me that camelot and camelot-py are "separate packages on the Python package index". Please try these and tell me what happens.

```
$ pip uninstall camelot
$ pip uninstall camelot-py
$ pip install camelot-py[cv]
```

Comment: I checked and your answer works fine now. There was this problem with my configuration that leads to the error. Thanks!